# Apache header cache-control issue

Tags: apache-2.2, internet-explorer

I have the following line in my apache config for a website:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

Part of the website generates CSVs that can be downloaded but in IE, with this line present in the config IE presents the following error:

```
Internet Explorer cannot download admin/ from wwww.domain.com
Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site.  The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.  Please try again later.
```

Is this a known issue with IE and is there a known fix?  Or is there a way to only implement the cache control on certain pages?

If I comment out that line it works fine in IE.

Can I add something like this to the < head > of pages that require it instead of the apache config line?

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-STORE, NO-CACHE, MUST-REVALIDATE, POST-CHECK=0, PRE-CHECK=0" />
```

Comment: What other headers are you sending with the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's the 'no-cache' header that's causing the problem:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308
- http://www.phord.com/experiment/cache/

Can you set an Expires header instead?